# 2D array of empty appendable items?

Tags: numpy, scipy

How do I make NxN 2D array of `empty((0))` elements in numpy? I would later loop the elements and append to each of them.

In 0D I do:

```
>>> a = empty((0))
>>> a 
array([], dtype=float64)
>>> a = append(a, 1)
>>> a = append(a, array([1,2]))
```

But how do I do it in 2D? How do I start from an NxN array of `empty((0))` values?

Answer (score 1):

I solved what I needed by entering third dimension:

```
allErrors = empty((len(xMesh), len(yMesh)))
allVals   = load(os.path.splitext(Gros[0])[0] + "_heights.npy")[:,:,newaxis]
...
for Gro in Gros[1:]:
    heightsNpy  = load(os.path.splitext(Gro)[0] + "_heights.npy")
    allVals = append(allVals, heightsNpy[:,:,newaxis], axis=2)
...
for i in range(len(xMesh)):
    for j in range(len(yMesh)):
        allErrors[i,j] = allVals[i,j,:].std(ddof=1)
```

My problem was to find standard deviation of each cell given multiple equally shaped 2D tables.